# databse not creating in collections mongo db

Tags: html, css, mongodb

I am working on a e-commerce website but its not creating dB for my web in mongo dB I am new to to mongo dB

```
const mongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient
const state={
    db:null
}
module.exports.connect=function(done){
    const url='mongodb://localhost:27017'
    const dbname='shopping'
    mongoClient.connect(url,(err,data)=>{
        if(err) return done (err)
    state.db=data.db(dbname)

    })
 
   done()


}
module.exports.get=function(){
    return state.db
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: [https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_create_db.asp#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20database%20in,make%20a%20connection%20to%20it](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_create_db.asp#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20database%20in,make%20a%20connection%20to%20it).

```
const url='mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping'
```

By adding dbname after '/' we create database